# Variational Inference with Normalizing Flows in Tensorflow Probability

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow-probability, bayesian-deep-learning, densevariational

In the last time I've read a little bit about using normalizing flows to improve variational inference f.e. [Link1](https://towardsdatascience.com/variational-inference-with-normalizing-flows-on-mnist-9258bbcf8810) [Link2](https://github.com/pierresegonne/VINF).

Tensorflow probability already offers RealNVP and MaskedAutoregressiveFlow in the bijector submodule as well as an AutoregressiveTransform layer in the layers submodule. Therefore I thought it would be easy and straight forward to build a Bayesian Neural Network
trained with variational inference and a posterior given by a normalizing flow using Tensorflow Probability.

Starting from one of the tutorials ([Link](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/examples/Probabilistic_Layers_Regression)) I was able to build a BNN with a mean_field_posterior.

Then things started to get complicated. I wrote the following function, adapted from this example ([Link](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/layers/AutoregressiveTransform)), to produce a posterior where a normal distribution is transformed using masked autoregressive flows.

```
def posterior_vi_maf(kernel_size, bias_size=0, dtype=None):
    n = kernel_size + bias_size
    return tf.keras.Sequential(
        [
            tfk.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(0,), dtype=tf.float32),
            tfpl.DistributionLambda(
                lambda t: tfd.MultivariateNormalDiag(
                    loc=tf.zeros(tf.concat([tf.shape(t)[:-1], [4]], axis=0)),
                    scale_diag=tf.ones(4),
                ),
            ),
            tfp.layers.AutoregressiveTransform(
                tfb.AutoregressiveNetwork(
                    params=2, hidden_units=[10, 10], activation="relu"
                )
            ),
        ]
    )
```

Comparing shape and output of posterior_vi_maf and posterior_mean_field it seems as if everything should, from a technical point of view, work.

```
p1 = posterior_vi_maf(16, 4, dtype=tf.float32)
p2 = posterior_mean_field(16, 4, dtype=tf.float32)
assert p1(x).shape == p2(x).shape
assert isinstance(p1(x), tfd.Distribution)
assert isinstance(p2(x), tfd.Distribution)
```

Unfortunately running the training script (see bottom) raises the following error message:

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for '{{node dense_variational/BiasAdd}} = BiasAdd[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC"](dense_variational/MatMul, dense_variational/split:1)' with input shapes: [?,?,16], [?,16].
```

Any suggestions why this happens and / or how I can fix this?

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

tfd = tfp.distributions
tfk = tf.keras
tfl = tf.keras.layers
tfpl = tfp.layers
tfb = tfp.bijectors

np.random.seed(2)
tf.random.set_seed(2)
N = 100

x = tfd.Normal(loc=0, scale=1).sample(N)
y = tfd.Normal(loc=x * 0.5, scale=0.3).sample()


def negloglik(y_true, y_pred):
    nll = -tf.reduce_mean(y_pred.log_prob(y_true))
    return nll


def prior(kernel_size, bias_size=0, dtype=None):
    n = kernel_size + bias_size
    return lambda t: tfd.Independent(
        tfd.Normal(loc=tf.zeros(n, dtype=dtype), scale=1),
        reinterpreted_batch_ndims=1,
    )


def posterior_mean_field(kernel_size, bias_size=0, dtype=None):
    n = kernel_size + bias_size
    c = np.log(np.expm1(1.0))
    return tf.keras.Sequential(
        [
            tfp.layers.VariableLayer(2 * n, dtype=dtype),
            tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(
                lambda t: tfd.Independent(
                    tfd.Normal(
                        loc=t[..., :n],
                        scale=1e-5 + 0.01 * tf.nn.softplus(c + t[..., n:]),
                    ),
                    reinterpreted_batch_ndims=1,
                )
            ),
        ]
    )


model = tf.keras.Sequential(name="small_vi_nn")
model.add(tfl.Input(1))
model.add(
    tfpl.DenseVariational(
        units=16,
        make_posterior_fn=posterior_vi_maf,
        make_prior_fn=prior,
        kl_weight=1 / N,
        kl_use_exact=False,
        activation="relu",
    )
)
model.add(
    tfpl.DenseVariational(
        units=2,
        make_posterior_fn=posterior_mean_field,
        make_prior_fn=prior,
        kl_weight=1 / N,
        kl_use_exact=False,
    )
)
model.add(
    tfpl.DistributionLambda(
        make_distribution_fn=lambda t: tfd.Normal(
            loc=t[:, 0],
            scale=1e-3 + tf.math.softplus(0.05 * t[:, 0]),
        )
    )
)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01, amsgrad=True)


model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=negloglik)
model.fit(
    x,
    y,
    epochs=2,
    shuffle=True,
    verbose=True,
)
```